# R read.table skip argument inconsistent across platforms

Tags: r, read.table

I run R on two different platforms:

One on Windows:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again
```

The other on Ubuntu/Linux:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.4                         
year           2021                        
month          02                          
day            15                          
svn rev        80002                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
nickname       Lost Library Book
```

To my utter dismay, I find that running `read.table` with identical `skip` arguments return **different** results on the two systems.

When I run the following command `read.table("data2.txt", skip = 6, fill = F, sep = "\t")` on Windows I get:

```
> read.table("data2.txt", skip = 6, fill = F, sep = "\t")
   V1                                     V2 V3 V4
1  NA                             Aerococcus  3  3
2  NA             Enterobacter / Citrobacter  4  4
3  NA                  Enterococcus faecalis  3  3
4  NA                   Enterococcus faecium  4  4
5  NA                       Escherichia coli 35 35
6  NA                             Klebsiella  7  7
7  NA Morganella / Providencia / P. vulgaris  1  1
8  NA                      Proteus mirabilis 10 10
9  NA                 Pseudomonas aeruginosa 10 10
10 NA                               Serratia  2  2
11 NA                  Staphylococcus aureus  3  3
```

Running the same command on Linux I get:

```
> read.table("data2.txt", skip = 6, fill = F, sep = "\t")
   V1                                     V2     V3   V4
1  NA             Erreger-Gruppe / Intervall Gesamt 2019
2  NA                                 Gesamt     82   82
3  NA                             Aerococcus      3    3
4  NA             Enterobacter / Citrobacter      4    4
5  NA                  Enterococcus faecalis      3    3
6  NA                   Enterococcus faecium      4    4
7  NA                       Escherichia coli     35   35
8  NA                             Klebsiella      7    7
9  NA Morganella / Providencia / P. vulgaris      1    1
10 NA                      Proteus mirabilis     10   10
11 NA                 Pseudomonas aeruginosa     10   10
12 NA                               Serratia      2    2
13 NA                  Staphylococcus aureus      3    3
```

You can download `data2.txt` from [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cxknhbbi3df3ubd/AACezLXEEXkWJnNLc5akBi-1a?dl=0).

Is there a way to make the behaviour of the two commands consistent? Unfortunately I don't see how to correct for line endings in `read.table`

Thank you.

Comment: Does `comment.char="\r"` help?

Answer (score 1):

It contains weird newlines. Open it in `mg` for example:

[image]

If I delete that extra carriage return on line 3, and read it with skip=4, it seems fine:

linux:

```
> read.table("data2.txt", skip = 4, header=T, fill = F, sep = "\t")
    X             Erreger.Gruppe...Intervall Gesamt X2019
1  NA                                 Gesamt     82    82
2  NA                             Aerococcus      3     3
3  NA             Enterobacter / Citrobacter      4     4
4  NA                  Enterococcus faecalis      3     3
5  NA                   Enterococcus faecium      4     4
6  NA                       Escherichia coli     35    35
7  NA                             Klebsiella      7     7
8  NA Morganella / Providencia / P. vulgaris      1     1
9  NA                      Proteus mirabilis     10    10
10 NA                 Pseudomonas aeruginosa     10    10
11 NA                               Serratia      2     2
12 NA                  Staphylococcus aureus      3     3
```

windows:

[image]

If you go one step deeper and look at the file byte for byte, you will see that it indeed has two carriage returns (`0D`) in succession (it shouln't have had), instead of the expected sequence `0D0A` for newline as windows likes them):

[image]

### Better way

If you use `data.table::fread` it seems to do the right thing regardless of misplaced carriage returns:

`dim( data.table::fread("data2.txt") )` gives `12 4` on both linux and windows.